# Jenkinsのセッションタイムアウト時間変更方法

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, jenkins

ubuntu16.04上のJenkinsのセッションタイムアウト時間を変更する方法を教えてもらえませんか？

Answer (score 1):

起動時のパラメータか

```
java -jar jenkins.war --sessionTimeout=60
```

Jenkinsのweb.xmlでできるようです。

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```